# Apk installed in bin but not found in emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, mobile

```
[2015-10-31 18:16:55 - Lab5] Performing sync
[2015-10-31 18:16:55 - Lab5] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Android'
[2015-10-31 18:16:55 - Lab5] Uploading Lab5.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2015-10-31 18:16:56 - Lab5] Installing Lab5.apk...
[2015-10-31 18:17:06 - Lab5] Success!
[2015-10-31 18:17:06 - Lab5] /Lab5/bin/Lab5.apk installed on device
[2015-10-31 18:17:06 - Lab5] Done!
```

Comment: Post your manifest xml here.

Comment: You APK was installed *from* the bin/ directory of your project tree.  Where it ends up on the phone depends on the Android version, but it is not a place called "bin" for any known version of Android.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the LAUNCHER category for your main Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml. Example:

```
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```